# Parameters of לא תעשון כן לה' אלקיכם

Tags: halacha, gentiles, synagogue, noahidism, parashat-reeh

There is a prohibition to destroy a synagogue based on the verse (Deut. 12:4) לא תעשון כן לה' אלקיכם, "you shall not do so unto the Lord your God." Rambam, in the minyan hamitzvot at the beginning of Sefer Ha-Madda (negative commandment 65), records this prohibition as follows:

> שלא לאבד בית המקדש, או בתי כנסייות, ובתי מדרשות; וכן אין מוחקין את
>   השמות המקודשין, ואין מאבדין את כתבי הקודש, שנאמר אבד תאבדון . . .
>   ואשריהם תשרפון, לא תעשון כן לה' אלוהיכם

My question is whether this prohibition applies to monotheistic places of worship that are not Jewish--for example, would it apply to a Unitarian church, a Baha'i temple, or an Islamic mosque? What about a Noahide synagogue? To be clear, my question is about the parameters of this specific prohibition, not about other reasons why one shouldn't destroy non-Jewish places of worship.

Comment: I assume that by "destruction" you mean totally dismantling the building, correct? There are numerous former churches, for example, that are now shuls. (One beautiful such place is in Rochester, NY.) Technically, they "destroyed" part of the church by removing the crosses, some plaques, paintings and overhauling the interior and exterior structure of the building.

Comment: @dan no that's not a good assumption. even destroying bits of the building could be problematic. but anyway why are you discussing destroying churches which are houses of avoda zara?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why? The question seems unclear.

Comment: Somewhat related http://www.timesofisrael.com/netanyahu-we-could-easily-destroy-al-aqsa-but-we-dont-want-to/ and http://www.jpost.com/Jewish-World/Jewish-Features/Can-Third-Temple-be-built-without-destroying-Dome-of-the-Rock

Comment: Are you asking about any monotheistic religion or only one that worships (the true) God? If the former, I don't understand why (after all, the verse refers to God); if the latter, I recommend you clarify that in the question. (Or perhaps you are of the opinion that every monotheistic religion worships God? I have no reason to think that that's the case, personally.)

Comment: @DanF If renovations to a shul are okay, churches can't be worse.

Comment: @wfb One thing that could make a difference - let's take a place of worship in which they serve the sun, and solely the sun. That's monotheistic. Do you think that's included? I doubt it. So the parameters of the question would seem to be limited to monotheistic religions *that serve Hashem,* even a distorted version thereof.

Answer (score 2):

According to an [anonymous person on the internet](https://www.bhol.co.il/Forums/topic.asp?whichpage=3&topic_id=1250712):

> ושמעתי ממו"ר הרב נבנצאל שליט"א, שגם מסגד אסור לפוצץ, כי גם הוא נבנה
> לשם שמים!

On the other hand, R. Yaakov Ariel discusses this at length in his [באהלה של תורה חלק ה סימן א.](https://www.toraland.org.il/22803) He concludes that this issur would not pertain to a mosque:

> עיי"ש שהביא מתשובת ר' יצחק אלחנן, שמותר ליהודי להתפלל במסגד, כי אינו
> בית ע"ז, וכבר נהגו יהודי חברון להתפלל במערת המכפלה במקום המסגד. אולם
> גם לדעתו מסתבר שאין למסגד קדושת מקום תפילה, ועל אחת כמה וכמה שאין לו
> מעמד של ביכנ"ס, שהרי לא ייתכן שהתורה תתן מעמד של קדושה למבנה הקורא תגר
> על התורה. אמנם עובדים בו את אותו הא-ל שאנו עובדים לו, אולם מתוך כפירה
> בתורת משה, ותורת משה היא האומרת "לא תעשון כן".
>
> לכן **נראה למסקנה, שמבנה שנבנה ע"י מי שאינו מכיר במשה ובתורתו שניתנה לו
> בסיני אין לו שום מעמד הלכתי, ואינו בכלל "בתי הא-ל יתעלה" שהזכיר
> הרמב"ם**. ומכל שכן לדעת הר"ן וסיעתו, הסוברים שכל קדושת בית כנסת אינה אלא
> מדרבנן, סביר להניח שרבנן לא החילו קדושה על בית תפילה שאינו מכיר בהם
> ובמשנתם....יתרה מזו: **יתכן אפילו שיש איסור בהריסת מסגד, מאחר שדינו כדין כל מקום המשמש לעבודת הא-ל. ואין הבדל בין אם העובדים בו ישראלים או נוכרים, שהרי גם מהם מצפה ה' שיעבדוהו**.
> להנחתנו האחרונה, שייתכן שמסגד נחשב כבית עבודת הא-ל, יש השלכות לדיוננו.
> כי אם נקבל הנחה זו, נמצא שאין היתר להרוס מסגד, וממילא אין הצדקה להרוס
> ביכנ"ס בידים על מנת למנוע את הפיכתו למסגד, שהרי גם למסגד יש מעין
> "קדושה" כביכול. אך אם נניח שמסגד אינו מקום הראוי לעבודת הא-ל, יש היתר
> להורסו, וממילא יש הצדקה להרוס ביכנ"ס על מנת למנוע את חילולו בהפיכתו
> למסגד, שהרי אין בו שום קדושה, וכל קיומו הוא רק בבחינת הרמת יד כנגד
> הקדושה האמיתית. ואולי יש להביא ראיה לאסור הריסת מסגדים ממה שמצאנו
> בענין הבמות שבימי מלכי יהודה. במות אלו נבנו לשם שמים קודם בניית המקדש;
> ואף שנאסרו אחר כך בעבודה, נמנעו המלכים מלהרסם. רק חזקיהו המלך, שכיתת
> אפילו את נחש הנחושת שעשה משה משום שטעו אחריו, הרס גם את הבמות. ומכאן
> יש ללמוד שיש איסור בהריסת מקום שהתייחד לעבודת ה', גם אם העבודה שבו
> סותרת את תורת משה ואת בחירת המקדש, ובלבד שאין בה סממנים של עבודה
> זרה.
>
> וכן משמע מרש"י (מל"א יט,י), שיש איסור בנתיצת הבמות, שמפרש את תלונת
> אליהו על ישראל: "כי עזבו בריתך בני ישראל, את מזבחותיך הרסו" – שהכוונה
> היא להריסת המזבחות ששימשו כבמות היחיד. גם מזבח ה' ההרוס בהר הכרמל שימש
> במה בעבר, עיי"ש רש"י ורד"ק. מכאן משמע שכל מבנה המשמש לעבודת הא-ל, גם
> אם לא נבנה עפ"י ההלכה, ואף בניגוד לה, חלה עליו קדושה ואסור להורסו.
> ואולי מכאן למד הרמב"ם בקל וחומר, שלא רק מקדש אסור בנתיצה, אלא כל מבנה
> המשמש לעבודת ה'. וא"כ לכאורה יש מקום לומר, שגם מסגד המשמש לעבודת הא-ל
> אסור בנתיצה.
>
> אולם בשו"ת חתם-סופר (או"ח סי' לב) מחלק בין הבמות המוזכרות בספר מלכים –
> שאסור לנתצן כיון שהן נבנו בהיתר קודם שעת איסור הבמות, ולכן בקדושתן הן
> עומדות – לבין במות שנבנו באיסור ואין בהן שום קדושה, ועל כן אין בהן
> איסור נתיצה. ואע"פ שהיתה סיבה לנתוץ גם את הבמות שנבנו בהיתר, כשם שעשה
> מאוחר יותר חזקיהו המלך, מכל מקום יש ללמוד מכאן שנתיצה לשם מניעת מכשול
> אסורה, מצד עצמה, ורק בהוראת שעה הותרה....
>
> ועדיין צ"ע מהו גדר מסגד. אם יוגדר כמקום עבודת הא-ל, אכן אין הפגם גדול
> כל כך בהפיכת ביכנ"ס למסגד; אולם אם מסגד אינו בכלל הגדרה זו, נמצא שיש
> בהפיכת ביכנ"ס למסגד בעיה חמורה, שכדי למונעה אולי יש לשקול אפילו את
> הריסת בתי הכנסת בידים.
>
> יש לדון בכך גם מצד מעשה ההקדשה – האם ייחודו של מקום למסגד מגדיר אותו
> כ"בית תפילה" וכמקום קדוש מבחינה הלכתית? אמנם מצאנו שגוי יכול להקדיש
> נכס לגבוה, אולם זו גופא השאלה – האם ייחודו של מקום לבית תפילה מוסלמי
> נחשב להקדש? ...
>
> אך **לאחר העיון נראה להכריע שמסגד אינו נחשב בית תפילה, ואין בו שום
> קדושה.** לא מבעיא לדעת הרמב"ן והר"ן שהבאנו לעיל (פרק ב) – שקדושת
> ביכנ"ס אינה אלא מדרבנן, ויש להניח שרבנן החילו קדושה רק על ביכנ"ס הנוהג
> עפ"י ההלכה, ולא על בית תפילה אחר שאינו מכיר בהם ובמשנתם – אך גם לדעת
> הרמב"ם, הסובר שכל מקום שבו עובדים לא-ל קדוש מהתורה, מסתבר שמסגד אע"פ
> שעובדים בו לא-ל אחד לא התקדש. משום שעבודת הא-ל שאליה מתכוון הרמב"ם היא
> רק עבודה שנצטוינו עליה מהתורה, אך פולחן זר שאינו מהתורה, ואף מנוגד
> לתורה, אינו בית עבודת הא-ל מהתורה. שהרי הם פולחים למכה, ולא אל המקום
> אשר בחר ה', ודבר זה סותר את סדר העבודה שקבעה התורה לדרוש רק אל המקום
> אשר יבחר ה'. ולאחר שנבחר המקום, כל סגידה למקום אחר דינה כדין במות בשעת
> איסורן. וזוהי כנראה כוונת שלמה בתפילתו עם חנוכת המקדש (מל"א ח, מא):
> "וגם אל הנכרי אשר לא מעמך ישראל הוא ובא מארץ רחוקה למען שמך... ובא
> והתפלל אל הבית הזה ... למען ידעון כל עמי הארץ... כי שמך נקרא על הבית
> הזה אשר בניתי." וכן בישעיה (נו, ו): "כי ביתי בית תפילה יקרא לכל העמים"
> – דוק: ביתי ולא ביתם. ובמקום אחר הדגיש (שם ב, ג): "כי מציון תצא תורה
> ודבר ה' מירושלים", ולא ממכה וממדינה.